# Para que serve as convenções de chamadas e qual delas utilizar?

Tags: c, c++

Para que serve as convenções de chamadas __fastcall, __stdcall, __thiscall, __cdecl, __fastcall e como saber qual delas utilizar?

Por exemplo, em alguma função que necessita ser chamada de forma mais rápida(poderia utilizar inline mas estou evitando por problemas de erros na compilação), pelo nome utilizaria a __fastcall, mas não sei se realmente é isso que ela faz ou se pode causar algum problema na função.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto serve para que o compilador gere código correto para passar os parâmetros para uma função mesmo que a rotina tenha sido compilada por outro compilador. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre isto aqui: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions